# explain using of hash in select method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I have a class in Model which has a hash defined.

```
{:"manager" => 1, :"staff" => 2}.freeze
```

in my form partial.

```
  <li class="field">
    <%= f.label :position_type %><br />
    <%= f.select :position_type, @person.position_types, {:include_blank => true} %>
  </li>
```

So, when I press `submit` button in the show.html.erb I could see only the values of the selected values but not keys which is what I intended to have.

**Q:** How can I tweak it so that it will show the `key` rather than `values`. I know it has much to do with `select` tag rather than `hash`.

PS:

1. I already used `array` and its doing what I want.
2. `hash.invert` which does show the `keys` in the show.html.erb but not in new/edit.html.erb and it being that way is not of that much help as user who tries to fill the form cannot memorise the keys => values to arrive on the keys as output.

I am just curious about how does the `select` in Rails takes the HTML `name` and `value` attirb. I am assuming that since **hash** already has `value` for each associated `key`, rails implicitly takes the `key's` `value` as HTML `value` attrib when form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html
the names and ids have to be in a nested array. To create that from your map you can use:

```
@person.position_types.map{|k,v| [k.to_s,v]}
```

Comment: I did place it in my form helper in `f.select` tag and it doesn't seem to work.